# Vim Still Flashing When It Shouldn't Be

Tags: vimrc

I have the following lines in my `.vimrc`:

```
" No annoying sound on errors
set noerrorbells
set novisualbell
set t_vb=
set tm=500
```

Which I believe should disable all visual/audio bells and flashes. However, vim still flashes when I'm on the first line and try to move up (`k`) or on the last line and try to move down (`j`). If I turn off visual flashes in my terminal profile preferences the behavior stops so this is not a redraw issue or something else. Why is this still happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recent Vims have the [`'belloff'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27belloff%27) setting. Simply set it to all to disable all bells:

```
:set belloff=all
```

That should fix the flashing issue for you. This needs a [Vim 7.4 > 793 patchlevel](http://ftp.vim.org/vim/patches/7.4/7.4.793).

Read the help at `:h 'belloff'` for all the possible values.

Answer (score 2):

[`:h visualbell`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27visualbell%27) says:

```
Use visual bell instead of beeping.  The terminal code to display the
visual bell is given with 't_vb'.  When no beep or flash is wanted,
use ":set vb t_vb=".
```

Note the last sentence.

You should, instead, do:

```
set noerrorbells
set visualbell
set t_vb=
```

Disabling `visualbell` enabled audio beeps, and the terminal emulator probably converted that to flashing.